# Integer vs Numeric Datatype in R

Tags: r, vector, integer, numeric

[This is a question I had while going through R programming course from Coursera. I had asked this question in their forums, but didn't get any answer.](https://class.coursera.org/rprog-034/forum/thread?thread_id=42)

So I thought, I should ask it here.

As I understand what Professor was talking about in that lecture - by default, when we store any number value in variable such as shown below

```
x <- 1
x

# prints numeric
class(x)
```

But why is it that when we store a vector such as shown below **(note: still without the 'L' symbol to force it as an integer)**

```
x <- 1:10
x

# prints "integer", but why?
class(x)
```

I thought it should give me a numeric vector, but it is not the case.

Can anybody please explain what is happening here?

Comment: See the *Value* section of `help(":")`.

Comment: Downvoter. Care to comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has been discussed, see http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Integer-vs-numeric-td847329.html
From `help(":")`

```
Value:

     For numeric arguments, a numeric vector.  This will be of type
     'integer' if 'from' is integer-valued and the result is 
     representable in the R integer type, otherwise of type '"double"'
     (aka 'mode' '"numeric"').
```